# Faker get location data that matches each other

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, faker, factory-boy

Im using faker and factory boy to populate my database with fake data. Currently, I'm working with location.

The setup that I'm running now populates the table but is mismatched.

```
class LocationFactory(DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = Location

    city = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: FAKE.city())
    street = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: FAKE.street_name())
    state = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: FAKE.city_suffix())
    country = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: FAKE.country())
    placeId = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: FAKE.pystr())
    latitude = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: FAKE.latitude())
    longitude = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: FAKE.longitude())
```

so when i run this I get city/stret/state/lat/long in correct format but it's random. The city is in US but the country is somewhere in Europe and the coordinates are in artica.

What was naively trying to do is to use

```
FAKE.local_latlng(country_code= 'US')
```

like this

```
class LocationFactory(DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = Location

    geo_data = FAKE.local_latlng(country_code= 'US')

    city = geo_data[2]
    street = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: FAKE.street_name())
    state = geo_data[4]
    country = geo_data[3]
    placeId = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: FAKE.pystr())
    longitude = geo_data[0]
    latitude = geo_data[1]
```

but we all know that this does not work in django

How can I get

```
FAKE.local_latlng(country_code= 'US')
```

to work